# Android root sandbox?

Tags: root-access, security, antivirus, sandboxing

On Windows I would use a sandbox to easily see file-changes made by shady programs to see how it would affect my system. What are easy methods (except decompiling and looking at the actual program code) for that on android?

Background: I ran the app 'stubborn trojan remover' showing me I'm infected with `ghost push`, a trojan for android. I looked up more information, but it seems there is very little. 'Stubborn trojan remover' gives also very little info, it doesn't even say where it removes the trojan from or where it found it.

Comment: You could run your program in the Android emulator on a computer, instead of on a real device. You can look at all the files on the Android emulator.

Comment: I'm looking for easy alternatives that you can do on the spot, maybe even on the phone

Comment: I don't think you're gonna find an app for that, because most phones just don't have enough capacity to emulate another phone

Comment: I guess the broader question is, are there easy ways to get a glimpse of what apps/programs are actually doing